# Prove that $\frac{n^2−3n}{2}$ cannot be prime for $n>5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that the expression $\frac{n^2−3n}{2}$ cannot be prime for $n$ greater than or equal to $5.$

If $n$ is even, then $n^2$ is also even since the square of any even number is even. Additionally, $3n$ is also even. Even - even = even. Therefore, the expression results in an even number divided by $2$. But sometimes even numbers divided by two are prime, like for $\frac{14}{2} = 7.$ So I appear to have contradicted myself. I think it has something to do with the greater than $5$ bit but I'm not sure how to formalize that.

Comment: Since $n^2-3n=n(n-3)$, and $n$ and $n-3$ always have opposite parity, the numerator is always a multiple of $2$; your expression is always an integer.

Comment: Maybe try to prove that $n(n-3)$ can't be equal to 2 times a prime?

Comment: Hint: $\,ab$ is composite if $\,a,b>1$. Apply that to $ab = n((n\!-\!3)/2),\,$ for $n$ odd, or $\,(n\!-\!3)(n/2)\,$ for $n$ even, using $n > 5\ \ $

Comment: @mathelp Welcome to Math SE. Your first paragraph states "... for n greater than or equal to 5", but $n = 5$ gives that $\frac{n^2-3n}{2}=5$, which is prime. Your statement near the end of "I think it has something to do with the greater than 5 bit ..." indicates what you wrote earlier is incorrect, i.e., it should be "... for n greater than 5" instead, which is a valid statement.

Comment: Once the way is clear, please delete the question since we already have too many questions like this.

Comment: The title is wrong. You need $n > 5$, not $n \geq 5$. For $n = 5$, the expression is equal to $5$, which is a prime.

Comment: I’m voting to close [and downvote] this question because this type of question has been asked many times on here, and this one is particularly straightforward.

Comment: @Mike it could be that the other proofs in the other answers are not what this user is looking for.  I've come up with a unique proof below using $\Omega$.  Please consider reversing your vote.  Thanks! =)

Answer (score 5):

We can write:
$$\frac{n^2-3n}{2} = n \cdot\frac{(n-3)}{2}$$

Suppose $n$ is odd. Then $\frac{n-3}{2}$ is an integer and since $n>5$, we must have $\frac{n-3}{2} >1$. So $n$ is a factor of $\frac{n^2-3n}{2}$ that is not $1$ or $\frac{n^2-3n}{2}$, which means that $\frac{n^2-3n}{2}$ is not prime.

Suppose $n$ is even. Then we may write $n = 2k$. Thus, we have
$$n \cdot\frac{(n-3)}{2} = k \cdot (n-3)$$

Since $n>5$, we know that $k>1$, $k$ is also not $n \cdot\frac{(n-3)}{2}$, which shows again that $\frac{n^2-3n}{2}  $ is not prime.

Comment: I'm actually a prime number addict.  How about you?  I want to get into a good AnNT book.  It's so mysterious to me how you can prove infnitude of primes in 3 sentences, yet a 200 page papers still haven't reached proof of any of the other prime gaps than 0.

Answer (score 1):

A number $x$ is prime iff the prime Omega function $\Omega(x) = 1$.  We can extend the usual $\Omega(x)$ to all of $\Bbb{Q}_{\gt 0}$ by defining $\Omega(x/y) := \Omega(x) - \Omega(y)$.  Then what you've got is called a surjective group homomorphism from the group of multiplicative, positive rationals.  I.e $\Omega: \Bbb{Q}_{\gt 0} \to \Bbb{Z}$ is a group homomorphism.

Now apply $\Omega$ to your expression $x = \frac{n^2 - 3n}{2}$.  We have:

$$
\Omega(\frac{n(n-3)}{2}) = \Omega(n) + \Omega(n-3) - \Omega(2) = \Omega(n) + \Omega(n-3) - 1.
$$

Since $n \gt 5 \gt 1$ we have that $\Omega(n) \geq 1$.  Then the only way for the above formula to actually equal $1$ is if $\Omega(n) + \Omega(n-3) = 2$ which can only occur if both $\Omega(n) = \Omega(n-3) = 1$.  The only primes $n, n-3$ are $5$ and $2$.  Prove that last statement. :)

QED

Comment: This was really great. One question, why does extending the function to be a surjective group homomorphism mean that it also "works" when we apply it to rational expressions?

For instance, if there was some other surjective homomorphism, would it also preserve this $\Omega(x)$ evaluating the "primality" of a rational expression?

Comment: @RichardKYu Great observation.  You're right, it might not work for example for $pq/r$, but in the comments they mentioned it's always an integer, your expression.